# Custom Managed Object missing file and edit on Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, financialforce

I'm currently trying to have my users on Salesforce1 edit records and upload pictures from their phone to the associated record. They currently have the edit button overridden to their custom visualforce page and I can't seem to get it to default back to the regular pages. I'm not sure if the overridden button is whats preventing the edit button from appearing on the layout.

I've also enabled publisher actions and salesforce1 actions on the layout with the file button their. For some reason I can't see the file button on the actions menu. Any idea why I can't edit or file upload. I have administrator access to the entire org.

Comment: So if I Understand correctly ,your publisher action button is not coming correctly ?Or its something else?

Comment: Hi Mohith - See below with my response to tushar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just forgot to enable feed tracking

Answer (score 1):

If i have understand your question correctly then your button is not coming in Salsforce one action bar.

You have missed the checkbox on Visualforce to enabe the page for salesforce one and lightning.

Go to Develop > Visualforce page > select your page and check the checkbox. it will solve the problem.

Comment: It does let me add other buttons like add note. I can also edit the fields that appear on the layout. It just won't let me add an edit button or attach file button.

Comment: @DimlyAware did you enable the page for SF1?

Comment: Hi Tushar, I found the problem. I didn't setup feed tracking. I thought I had. Thank you for helping me with this!